# Django custom command and cron

Tags: django, django-admin, cron

I want my custom made Django command to be executed every minute. However it seems like `python /path/to/project/myapp/manage.py mycommand` doesn't seem to work while at the directory `python manage.py mycommand` works perfectly.

How can I achieve this ? I use `/etc/crontab` with:

```
****** root python /path/to/project/myapp/manage.py mycommand
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the problem is that cron is going to run your scripts in a "bare" environment, so your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is likely undefined.  You may want to wrap this up in a shell script that first defines DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings 
./manage.py mycommand
```

Make it executable (chmod +x) and then set up cron to run the script instead.

**Edit**

I also wanted to say that you can "modularize" this concept a little bit and make it such that your script accepts the manage commands as arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
./manage.py ${*}
```

Now, your cron job can simply pass "mycommand" or any other manage.py command you want to run from a cron job.

Comment: This says unknown command when I do it. I had to change it to:

cd /path/to/project

./manage.py ${*}

Comment: No success. The custom command is recognized but the command apparently can't find the database

Comment: What do you mean by "command apparently can't find the database"? Does that entail an error of some sort?

Answer (score 13):

```
cd /path/to/project/myapp && python manage.py mycommand
```

By chaining your commands like this, python will not be executed unless cd correctly changes the directory.

Comment: This was the easiest way to do it for me and it worked well. Thanks David!

Comment: that didn't work for me (still having a No module named django.core.management error in my mails)

Answer (score 9):

If you want your Django life a lot more simple, use django-command-extensions within your project:

http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/

You'll find a command named "runscript" so you simply add the command to your crontab line:

```
****** root python /path/to/project/myapp/manage.py runscript mycommand
```

And such a script will execute with the Django context environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i have done recently in one of my projects,(i maintain venvs for every project i work, so i am assumning you have venvs)

> ```
>  ***** /path/to/venvs/bin/python /path/to/app/manage.py command_name
> ```

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

**How to Schedule Django custom Commands on AWS EC-2 Instance?**

**Step -1**

```
First, you need to write a .cron file
```

**Step-2**

```
Write your script in .cron file.
```

> MyScript.cron

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/kuzo1/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Myproject/manage.py transfer_funds >> /home/ubuntu/Myproject/cron.log 2>&1
```

Where * * * * * means that the script will be run at every minute. you can change according to need (https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*). Where /home/ubuntu/kuzo1/venv/bin/python3 is python virtual environment path. Where /home/ubuntu/kuzo1/manage.py transfer_funds is Django custom command path & /home/ubuntu/kuzo1/cron.log 2>&1 is a log file where you can check your running cron log

**Step-3**

**Run this script**

```
$ crontab MyScript.cron
```

**Step-4**

**Some useful command**

```
1. $ crontab -l (Check current running cron job)
2. $ crontab -r (Remove cron job)
```

Answer (score 0):

The runscript extension wasn't well documented.  Unlike the django command this one can go anywhere in your project and requires a scripts folder.  The .py file requires a run() function.

Answer (score 0):

1. If its a standalone script, you need to do this:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.core.management import setup_environ
   setup_environ(settings)

   #your code here which uses django code, like django model
   ```
2. If its a django command, its easier: https://coderwall.com/p/k5p6ag

   In (management/commands/exporter.py)

   ```
   from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

   class Command(BaseCommand):
       args = ''
       help = 'Export data to remote server'

       def handle(self, *args, **options):
           # do something here
   ```

And then, in the command line:

```
$ python manage.py exporter
```

Now, it's easy to add a new cron task to a Linux system, using crontab:

```
$ crontab -e

or $ sudo crontab -e if you need root privileges
```

In the crontab file, for example for run this command every 15 minutes, something like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/15 * * * * python /var/www/myapp/manage.py exporter
```