# Interacting with a program in the background of Django

Tags: django, process, background

I have a program that classifies text and would like to make it interactive with a user on the front-end of my django site. The problem is it takes 20 seconds for the program to load the training set and get going, and that's not feasible every time someone enters input.

Instead, I'd like Django to load the program once when the server starts, and have all user input interact with it via a view.

I looked at launching subprocesses, but if I'm not mistaken, a subprocess would only be launched when a view is called and that is undesirable for this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) would be appropriate here.  There is Django integration available with [django-celery](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/).

Answer (score 2):

As Jim noticed *celery* is one of the best options you have for asynchronus task management, but if you want to avoid celery & its dependecies overhead you could just add a status field on the model the process takes place (e.g. *text_processed* boolean field with default=False) and create an application [management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) which would handle the process of the created db entries.

Add the [command on a cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601153/django-custom-command-and-cron) and you are done.