# Django custom manage command sometimes working, sometimes not, depending on the path

Tags: django, ubuntu

This story takes place under Ubuntu linux 10 with python 2.6.5.

I have created a new custom command in my django project call `taskserver`.

When I am in the project directory (which is `/opt/acme/python-site/acme/` and I execute

```
python manage.py taskserver
```

the custom command is started correctly.

When I am in `/opt/acme/` the following command executes my custom `taskserver` command:

```
python /opt/acme/python-site/acme/manage.py taskserver
```

When I am in `/opt/acme/deploy/` the following command (same as above) fails to execute my custom `taskserver` command:

```
python /opt/acme/python-site/acme/manage.py taskserver
```

It complains that:

```
Unknown command: 'taskserver'  
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Any idea why the current location matters even though I am specifying the full path to my manage.py file? I need to get this command running from a fabric script which resides in the deploy directory. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Take a lookt to  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601153/django-custom-command-and-cron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601153/django-custom-command-and-cron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the application with the management package is in your PYTHONPATH. Eg, if taskserver.py is in `/opt/acme/python-site/acme/management/commands/taskserver.py`

```
env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/acme/python-site/acme python /path/to/manage.py taskserver
```

In general, specifying the full path to manage.py won't necessarily set up your `PYTHONPATH` correctly.

Fabric may also have it's own methods of setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment var, I don't remember offhand. But using `env` should work regardless.

Comment: Also, this is an alternate way of making it work with fabric: `cd /opt/acme/python-site/acme/ && python manage.py taskserver`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
python ../python-site/acme/manage.py taskserver
```

when you are in `/opt/acme/deploy/` you must go back to previous dir. by `../` then you are in  `/opt/acme/` dir, here your path to `manage.py` is `../python-site/acme/manage.py`