# Could not import Django error after running manage.py runcrons in crontab (MacOs Sierra)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-cron

I'm using Django-Cron to schedule some database stuff. But after I edited my crontab like so:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/apple/Documents/Django/pricecompare/manage.py    runcrons >> /Users/apple/Documents/Django/pricecompare/app/log.txt"
```

I'm getting this error sent as **"mail"**:

```
 "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"
```

I'm not using any `virtual environment` by the way.

However, when I run the same script directly in the terminal, I don't get any error. I can import `Django` in the terminal as well.

Any solutions? I'm using python 2. and I might have copied the code that was supposed to be used in python 3, so I suspect that might be giving me the error.

Comment: Maybe: `*/1 * * * * /path/to/python /Users/apple/Documents/Django/pricecompare/manage.py`

Comment: When you run in terminal, it is running by the user you logined.But in crontab may be it is executed by root.So take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601153/django-custom-command-and-cron

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo Which code should I upload?

Comment: @itzmeontv I have tried all the fixes suggested in the link.

I got this error:

    /Users/apple/Documents/Django/pricecompare/cronscript.sh: line 1:   export: `=': not a valid identifier
    /Users/apple/Documents/Django/pricecompare/cronscript.sh: line 1:     export: `pricecompare.settings': not a valid identifier
    /Users/apple/Documents/Django/pricecompare/cronscript.sh: line 2: ./manage.py: No such file or directory